# How to share a folder and add permissions with C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to share a folder and its content and give read/write permission to "Everyone" programmatically.
It should be equivalent to the manual action in the following images.

http://imageshack.com/a/img910/7316/XiLb1E.png

http://imageshack.com/a/img674/7982/jhdQrw.png

I tried the listed code but it did share the folder, but without permissions. The user is able to see the folder but when he is trying to open it he get "Permission Denied".

```
Private Sub ShearFolder()

    Dim DI As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.IndexOf("bin")) & "DB")
    Dim Ds As DirectorySecurity = DI.GetAccessControl()
    Ds.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))
    DI.SetAccessControl(Ds)

    Dim MC As ManagementClass = New ManagementClass("Win32_Share")

    Dim inParam As ManagementBaseObject = MC.GetMethodParameters("Create")
    Dim OutParam As ManagementBaseObject

    inParam("Description") = "DB"
    inParam("Name") = "DB"
    inParam("Path") = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.IndexOf("bin")) & "DB"
    inParam("Type") = 0
    inParam("MaximumAllowed") = Nothing
    inParam("Access") = Nothing

    outParam = MC.InvokeMethod("create", inParam, Nothing)

    Dim ntAccount As NTAccount = New NTAccount("Everyone")

    Dim userSID As SecurityIdentifier = ntAccount.Translate(GetType(SecurityIdentifier))

    Dim utenteSIDArray(userSID.BinaryLength) As Byte
    userSID.GetBinaryForm(utenteSIDArray, 0)

    Dim userTrustee As ManagementObject = New ManagementClass(New ManagementPath("Win32_Trustee"), Nothing)
    userTrustee("Name") = "Everyone"
    userTrustee("SID") = utenteSIDArray

    Dim userACE As ManagementObject = New ManagementClass(New ManagementPath("Win32_Ace"), Nothing)
    userACE("AccessMask") = 2032127                                
    userACE("AceFlags") = AceFlags.ObjectInherit
    userACE("AceType") = AceType.AccessAllowed
    userACE("Trustee") = userTrustee


    Dim userSecurityDescriptor As ManagementObject = New ManagementClass(New ManagementPath("Win32_SecurityDescriptor"), Nothing)
    userSecurityDescriptor("ControlFlags") = 4 
    userSecurityDescriptor("DACL") = New Object() {userACE}

    MC = New ManagementClass("Win32_Share")
    Dim share As ManagementObject = New ManagementObject(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.IndexOf("bin")) & "DB" & ".Name='DB'")
    share.InvokeMethod("SetShareInfo", New Object() {Int32.MaxValue, "DB", userSecurityDescriptor})

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In a quick google search I found this
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?616267-Creating-shared-folders-and-specifying-share-permissions
Give it a try.